# Logging into Windows XP with a barcode

Tags: windows-xp

This is a question that is an extension of my previous "Free 3 of 9 Extended Barcode Font" question. I have a barcode that now will input a username & TAB & user's password. This barcode works fine in Word or Notepad but when I try it for the Windows Log-in Screen the tab function does not work in my barcode. The barcode simply inputs, for example, garyv$Igaryv1! into the username text box of the Log-in Screen and then auto enters giving me an error message directing me to include a password. Does anyone know why the tab function does not work and how to get the it to work for the Log-in Screen with a barcode? Please help, I am soooo frustrated with this probelm right now.

Comment: no idea, but for the record it's not a good idea from a security point-of-view

Comment: well... you could say the same thing about windows itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the windows logon screen grabs the usual key handling routines to protect itself from keyloggers. Maybe that's interfering with your hook somehow. no idea what the fix would be.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a code128 barcode. Save the code as `.htm`:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var p1="211214413111121124121241121124111224121421411311142112232121134111111242112";
var p2="2141212411211244131111211241421122211141222311411221341114131112211322331112";

var code=p1+p2;

document.write("<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
document.write("<tr>");
for(x=0; x<code.length; x++)
{
    if(x%2==0)
        document.write("<td width='" + code.substr(x,1) + "' height='40' bgcolor='black'></td>");
    else
        document.write("<td width='" + code.substr(x,1) + "' height='40' bgcolor='white'></td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</table>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering the Tab character or the key code for the Tab key?  I don't think they're the same.

Sending the Tab character '\t' to the login screen probably won't work.  Sending the keyboard scan code for tab should be indistinguishable to Windows.

Comment: I am using the key code for the tab key, which is $I for the Code 39 barcode, and like I said it works in Word, but not on the Log-in Screen and that is wher I need to have it work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your previous question.  Looking here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39, I see that $I is the the Tab character.

Windows knows the difference between someone pressing the Tab key on the keyboard and someone entering a tab character.

For example, in Word you can hold down Alt and press 09 to insert a tab character.  This will not work to move to the next field in a dialog box.

Comment: Anything else you can think of to use? I really don't know where to go with this problem, I have hit a wall and I am stuck!